# Submitting a form with an action that includes a hash

Tags: html, forms, get

I have what you would call 2 "sections" on a page and the user can submit a form on the 2nd section, however if they get an error the page will reload and take them to the top of the page again...... this is annoying behavior and I want them to be taken back down to the correct spot on the page to see the error etc..

I figured I could just give the element an `id` such as:

```
<section id="my_section"></section>
```

...and then in the `action` method of the form I could input the anchor such as:

```
<form action="page.php#my_section" method="post">..........</form>
```

This works in all the browsers I tried it in, but I was wondering if this type of method has been known to cause any issues in any browsers including ones in mobiles/tablets or with certain `method` types such as `GET`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all modern browsers, the method you are using is perfectly fine.  That's what hashtags are made for.  However, it might be better if you try to **keep the form from submitting when there's an error** (using `return false` in JS). I'm not sure if that's possible in your case, but if you can, it will keep users from having to re-input values into the form.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I very rarely use JS error checking as it's not a secure method and if I do I always do server error checking as well; as for users having to re-input the data - I make sure I always repopulate that for them on errors :)